How to change actively selected menu item color/shape in Android Studio
Problem:
The background of the selected "Home" tab is a light pink and also an oval. I'd like to 1. change the shape to a rounded square and 2. know how to change the color.

Here is the home page xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F5F5F5"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_button_background"
            android:backgroundTint="#1B1B3A"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_filter_list_alt_24"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ButtonAddOptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="Add button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_92"
        app:backgroundTint="#1B1B3A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/Platinum" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navbar"
        app:itemIconTint="#1B1B3A"
        app:itemTextColor="#1B1B3A"
        app:itemRippleColor="#91A7E8"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Here is the menu_navbar xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_24"
        android:iconTint="@color/Charcoal"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:title="Account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_24"
        android:iconTint="@color/Charcoal"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_24"
        android:iconTint="@color/Charcoal"
        />
</menu>

I've tried changing the default color scheme of the app and that successfully changes the background tint when the menu item is selected, but I have not found a way to change the shape, and on top of that I would still like deeper control of the color outside of preset themes.

Did you try app:shapeAppearance for the shape and android:color for the color, as mentioned in the documentation?

@CommonsWare Thank you! I wasn't aware of this Github documentation. I had been previously using Android Studio docs but they weren't nearly sufficient for my purposes.
Specifically the docs made me aware of the following attribute for BottomNavigationViews:
app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/CustomActiveIndicator"
And then I just created a custom indicator in my style.xml file:

